# Bash script shell input variables

Tags: bash, shell

I want automatize these commands:

```
qemu-arm -g 12358 exec &
gdb-multiarch -q --nh -ex 'set architecture arm' -ex 'file exec' -ex 'target remote localhost: 12358'
```

if I try to create this script

```
#!/bin/bash
read VAR1
qemu-arm -g "$VAR1" exec &
gdb-multiarch -q --nh -ex 'set architecture arm' -ex 'file exec' -ex 'target remote localhost: "$VAR1"'
```

it doesn't works and I get this output

```
The target architecture is assumed to be arm
Reading symbols from exec...
localhost: "$VAR1": cannot resolve name: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
localhost: "$VAR1": No such file or directory.
```

I'm not a expert about bash script but i think the problem is about " " of second VAR1, there is a way for fix it?

Comment: Variables aren’t expanded within single quotes.

Comment: In this situation of trying to understand what's going on, try to activate tracing mode, as explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554411/279171). You will get your command lines expanded, just before they will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes around this argument:

```
-ex 'target remote localhost: "$VAR1"'
```

are preventing the shell from expanding the your variable `$VAR1`.

You could try with double quotes instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
read VAR1
qemu-arm -g "$VAR1" exec &
gdb-multiarch -q --nh -ex 'set architecture arm' -ex 'file exec' -ex "target remote localhost: $VAR1"
```